# How to use `DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.RequestJWTApplicationToken`

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying use method `RequestJWTApplicationToken` to authenticate and create a envelope, like the code below:

```
private OAuthToken _authToken;
protected static ApiClient _apiClient { get; private set; }


public string GetToken()
{
    _authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTApplicationToken(
        "<ClientId>",
        "<AuthServer>",
        "<PrivateKeyBytes>",
        1,
        "<Scopes>");
}

public void SendDocumentForSignature()
{
    var envelope = MakeEnvelope("my_email@domain.com", "my name");
    
    var token = GetToken();

    var apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");

    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
    EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope("<AccountId>", envelope);

    string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;
}
```

But I received the exception below, here `envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope("<AccountId>", envelope);`:

Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed. Authentication for System Application failed."

I didn't find any use cases about the `RequestJWTApplicationToken` method in the documentation or in the" Quick Start "project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answers to your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequestJWTApplicationToken` can only be used with a very few DocuSign API methods related to organization management. All of of the eSignature REST API methods require an access token that is associated with a user in an account.

To create such access tokens using the OAuth JWT flow, use the C# [`RequestJWTUserToken`](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs#L948) method.

The associated user for some use cases is a "system user" such as "finance@example.com" For other use cases, the user will be a specific named user.